# How to add active class in pagination with PHP

Tags: php, css, pagination

This is my pagination code:

```
<div class="pagination">
<a href='?page=1'>1</a>
<a href='?page=2'>1</a>
<a href='?page=2'>1</a>

</div>
```

I want to add class `active` to the active page. How to add it?

You can also help me make a code to add active class with `$_GET['page]`

Comment: You can do something very simple like 
for($i=0;$i<$numpages;$i++){
  echo "<a href='?page=$i'";
  if($_GET['page] == $i) echo " class='active'";
  echo ">$i</a>";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add an if statement onto each row checking if `$_GET['page']` equals the current page:

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href='?page=1'<? if ($_GET['page'] == 1) { echo ' class="active"'; } ?>>1</a>
    <a href='?page=2'<? if ($_GET['page'] == 2) { echo ' class="active"'; } ?>>2</a>
    <a href='?page=3'<? if ($_GET['page'] == 3) { echo ' class="active"'; } ?>>3</a>
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, you could do the whole thing in a loop which would help you when you want to add more rows:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    echo "<a href='?page=$i'";
    if ($_GET['page'] == $i) {
        echo ' class="active"';
    }
    echo ">$i</a>";
}
```

Comment: In the alternatively, can you write the code with "if else", instead of using shortcut please? It is hard to apply that on my complex code (it is more complex than i shown in the question)

Comment: Ok, I'm doing that now @ShilpaChoudhary